# cross browser testing, layout testing and continuous integration

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, cross-browser, continuous-integration

We have a large number of web applications developed at a fast pace. More often than not, we are unable to test them sufficiently on different browsers, leading to issues at times. (At the moment, we rely on developers to test their apps in different browsers.)

I am aware that I can use Selenium remote to test functioning of each app in different browser but that does not test the layout (is the top nav really on the top, does this long text break the layout, etc).

Is there an equivalent UI testing tool that could test not only the functionality but also the layout, even if on a high level?

Ideally, I would like to integrate these tests with a CI tool so we could keep a check on UI regression.

I don't know if this is even possible so checking - How do you test your apps in different browsers on a CI tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the [CI package from Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) allows you to specify which browser to use. Failing that, you can specify it in your Junit-exported Selenium Tests. Just keep an array of the browser identifiers and loop over them for each test - bear in mind that taking this road will make it harder to see which browser failed for which test.

Comment: thanks Gearóid. my main query was around the assertion of a layout, like saying here are 2 snapshot bitmaps, do they have at least a x % similarity. And obviously, if we have such a UI tool, can we integrate it with a CI server

Comment: doesn't look like layout testing is actually possible, so asserting on presence of elements is our best bet, and Selenium is good for that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MogoTest](http://www.mogotest.com).  When I last checked, it detected cross-browser layout differences.  I'm sure you could integrate it into a CI workflow.

Comment: [MogoTest has gone out of business](http://nirvdrum.com/2014/11/20/open-sourcing-mogotest.html)